# Formula for number of integers of the form $p_1p_2\cdots p_m \leq n$ with $p_k$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested in an formula for finding how many integers less than or equal to $n$ can be formed from multiplying exactly $m$ prime numbers. I will call this function $f(m, n)$. The case $m = 1$ is simply the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and [many algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Algorithms_for_evaluating_%CF%80(x)) exist for finding $f(m, n) = \pi(n)$.

For $m = 2$, I found [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A072000), which says that $$f(2, n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\pi\left(n/2 \right)} \left(\pi\left( \frac{n}{p_i} \right) \right) + \pi \left(\sqrt{n} \right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\pi(\sqrt{n})} \left( \pi \left(\frac{n}{p_i} \right)-i+1 \right)$$ where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime. For $m = 3$, there is [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A072114), but no formula for finding $f(3, n)$.

For a general $m$, I got that $$f(m, n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\pi(n)}\left(f(m-1, \frac{n}{p_i}) + 1 \right)$$

The problem with this formula is that it requires knowing all primes less than $n$, which is impractical for large values of $n$.

I am looking for a formula for $f(m, n)$ that requires knowing as low of the maximum prime as possible. With this standard, the second formula for $f(2, n)$ is superior to the first.

Edit: As Steven Clark pointed out in the comments, the general formula for $f(m, n)$ that I got is wrong.

Comment: You are looking for an exact formula for $f(m,n)$ with requiring knowing as few primes as possible?

Comment: @Ante Yep, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Seems possible only if you find recursion formula among the primes, i found a recursion "almost-formula", but it is still not developed enough to give true formula.

Comment: What sort of recursion formula do you mean? Something like the one in my question?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at project euler forums, but I'm quite sure there isn't a closed form for $f(m,n)$

Comment: In particular, look at Project Euler problem 10's forum, and search for *Lucy_Hedgehog*'s answer

Comment: Your formula for general $m$ doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: @GarethMa How would that $S(v, p)$ be related to my $f(m, n)$?

Comment: @StevenClark I did some testing with $m = 3$, and it seems that you are correct. What would the correct formula be?

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPrime.html for the correct formula.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks for that!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297785/prime-counting-meissel-lehmer-is-there-a-general-formula/300060#300060 (counted with multiplicity)